# Android movement follow finger

Tags: java, android, menu, android-linearlayout

I'm creating a custom menu for an Android application.

This menu is composed of two parts and at the start the first part is hidden, while the second is visible at the left of the screen.

Now what I'm trying to do, is to keep visible/invisible the hidden menu based on the user finger movement to right/left and this movement have to follow the finger.

The two menu are two `LinearLayout` and their root view is another `LinearLayout` with a vertical orientation.

I've started by using the Motion Events `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP`, but they don't allow me to follow the finger movement.

Thanks to all:)

Comment: They "allow" it if you store the finger position on `ACTION_DOWN` and check the new position on `ACTION_UP`. Now you can check for example `x1 > x2 && y1 == y2` (swiped to the left). Mind that this check should include a treshold, because no one (prove me wrong :P) can move his finger in a perfect straight line.

Comment: if i don't left the screen with my finger, it will not read the event ACTION_UP. Instead it have to follow my finger so, the action UP, will be read at the end of the movement

Comment: If you want to follow the fingers movement between `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP`, then you could use `ACTION_MOVE` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html). Store the first position on `ACTION_DOWN` and evaluate the direction by using the new position at event `ACTION_MOVE`.